# Create a custom list in sharepoint via Visual Studio [without Feature option]

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, custom-list

I've created a customlist in **Visual Studio 2013** and deployed the same in the **SharePoint 2013** server. Its working fine and is showing in the "**Site Settings -> Site Features**" area of my sharepoint site. This will allow the user to activate/deactivate it. But, my site may be a big one in size and I want to create a lot of lists via VisualStudio. So, Is it possible to avoid listing it in "**Site Features**" area ? This is not listing for lists available in  SharePoint, when we add it via UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your feature.xml set the `hidden = true;` by default its set to false!

```
<Feature
  ActivateOnDefault = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  AlwaysForceInstall = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  AutoActivateInCentralAdmin = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Creator = "Text" 
  DefaultResourceFile =  "Text"
  Description = "Text" 
  Hidden = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Id = "Text"
  ImageUrl = "Text"
  ImageUrlAltText = "Text"
  ReceiverAssembly = "Text"
  ReceiverClass = "Text"
  RequireResources = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Scope = "Text"
  SolutionId = "Text"
  Title = "Text"
  UIVersion = "Text"
  Version = "Text" >
</Feature>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436075.aspx

Answer (score 0):

when you create list by selecting list template. visual studio auto create site scoped feature if not available in your solution.
so your list will be created depending on your features.
i think it's not possible to avoid listing features in your Site Features area but you can hide it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have found a way to hidden the feature listing in Site Features area. There is an option called "Is Hidden" which should be changed to true. This has avoided my list's feature listing.